# Why isn't my code in C for adding digits not working for more than one digit?

Tags: c, project

I am currently learning to code and I wrote code on VSCode using C that takes in a number and adds the digits of the number until the sum of digits is one digit long. For example, add_digits(123) -> 1 + 2 + 3 = 6 and similarly add_digits(319) -> 3 + 1 + 9 = 13 -> 1 + 3 = 4
The code I wrote works with 1 digit inputs, but pauses then doesn't return anything with multiple digit inputs. Does anyone know why?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int add_digits(char *str);

int main(void){
    printf("Enter a number: ");
    char *str = malloc(10 * sizeof(char));
    if(str == NULL){
        return 0;
    }
    scanf("%s",str);
    int ans = add_digits(str);
    printf("Answer is %i",ans);
    free(str);
}


int add_digits(char *str){
    if(str == NULL){
        printf("Invalid input!\n");
        return 1;
    }
    if(strlen(str) == 1){
        return atoi(&str[0]);
    }
    int n = strlen(str);
    int sum = 0;
    for(int k = 0; k<n ; k++){
        char *p = &str[k];
        sum += atoi(p);
    }
    char *new = malloc(10 * sizeof(char));
    if(new== NULL){
        return 0;
    }
    itoa(sum,new,10);
    int result = add_digits(new);
    free(new);
    return result;
}
```

The code I wrote works with 1 digit inputs, but pauses then doesn't return anything with multiple digit inputs. Does anyone know why?

Comment: Aside: there is no need to dynamically allocate `str` in `main`.

Answer (score 1):

1. `char *p = &str[k]` points to position `k` of the string, and `atoi()` will process `str[k]` through `str[n-1]`.  If you want to do this then write code that converts a single byte (like below) and then you can just do that for `str[k]` (no need for the `char *p`).
2. Always use a maximum field width when reading a string with `scanf()`.  Otherwise you program is vulnerable to buffer overflow.
3. As you know the size of your `str[]` at compile time it's easier to use a regular stack allocated variable.
4. `atoi()` doesn't have proper error handling.  Use `strtol()` is you don't want to use what I have below.
5. You return on error but it overlap with the normal value domain.  Per @Chris changed it to -1.
6. There is no need to handle `1` digit different than `n`.
7. `&str[0]` is fine but you could just write is `str`.
8. If your input is small consider having `scanf()` convert your string to the appropriately sized integer (`unsigned int`, `unsigned long`, or `unsigned long long`).  `add_digits()` process the input from least significant number but otherwise very similar logic:

```
int add_digits(unsigned v) {
    int i = 0;
    for(; v; v /= 10) {
        i += v % 10;
        i = i / 10 + i % 10;
    }
    return i;
}
```

Here's a simplified version:

```
#include <ctype.h>
#include <stdio.h>

#define STR_LEN 10
#define str(s) str2(s)
#define str2(s) #s

int add_digits(char *str) {
    if(!str) {
        printf("Invalid input!\n");
        return -1;
    }
    int i = 0;
    for(; *str; str++)
        if(isdigit(*str)) { // error if not a digit?
            i += *str - '0';
            i = i / 10 + i % 10;
        }
    return i;
}

int main(void) {
    printf("Enter a number: ");
    char str[STR_LEN+1];
    scanf("%" str(STR_LEN) "s", str);
    printf("Answer is %i\n", add_digits(str));
}
```

Example session:

```
Enter a number: 12345
Answer is 6
```

Comment: I know the behavior comes straight from the OP, but how is the error detected if `add_digits` could return `1` for `add_digits("1")`? I might suggest `-1` as a sentinel value.

Comment: @Chris Op prints an error message.  That said, you are right, and I fixed it as suggested.  Thanks.

Comment: Agree that the input should be turned into a number first. This is using linearity of a congruence relation to simplify and optimize the instructions in a way that is not obvious. Pretty!

Answer (score 0):

A first note: you are doing dynamic memory allocation when you don't need to. If you're allocating memory in a function and freeing it before the function ends, it probably doesn't need to be dynamically allocated unless you're allocating more memory than will fit on the stack.

Your function has a loop which appears to take a string input like `"123"` and accesses substrings `"123"`, `"23"` and `"3"`. Each of these it uses `atoi` to convert to integers, and adds to `sum`.

All of this is much more complicated than it needs to be. Instead, let's just iterate over each character in the string until we find the null terminator. Each character is converted to the corresponding int value with some basic math and added to `sum`. *This does not detect errors if non-numeric characters are present.*

```
int add_digits(char *str) {
    int sum = 0;
    for (char *ch = str; *ch; ch++) 
        sum += *ch - '0';

    return sum;
}
```

Now, this will only sum the digits *once* and not until the sum is a single digit. For that, we do need some other looping mechanism.

Let's store the string representation in a new char array that we can manipulate. We'll need to sum at least *once* so a do/while loop is a good fit. Within we'll sum the digits, but then use `sprintf` to update `str2` in the event we need to rerun the summation.

```
int add_digits(char *str) {
    char str2[strlen(str) + 1];
    strcpy(str2, str);

    int sum;
    do {
        sum = 0;
        for (char *ch = str2; *ch; ch++)
            sum += *ch - '0';

        sprintf(str2, "%d", sum);
   } while (sum > 9);

    return sum;
}
```